# about convergence of $\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{\sin \left(\frac{x}{k}\right)}{\sqrt{k}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

the radio test fail but it seem to converger numerically
$$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{\sin \left(\frac{x}{k}\right)}{\sqrt{k}}=\sqrt{2 \pi } \sqrt{x}+\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\right) \left(e^{-2 \sqrt{\pi } \sqrt{i n} \sqrt{x}} \sin \left((1+i) \sqrt{2 \pi } \sqrt{n} \sqrt{x}\right)+e^{-2 \sqrt{\pi } \sqrt{-i n} \sqrt{x}} \sinh \left((1+i) \sqrt{2 \pi } \sqrt{n} \sqrt{x}\right)\right)}{\sqrt{n}}$$ I do not sure

Comment: Use $|\sin x| \leq |x|$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is convergent, since $\left|\sin\left(\frac xk\right)\right|\leqslant\frac{|x|}k$, which implies that$$\left|\frac{\sin\left(\frac xk\right)}k\right|\leqslant\frac{|x|}{k^{3/2}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Note that the inequality $|\sin(t)|\leq t$ implies that
$$\left|\frac{\sin \left(\frac{x}{k}\right)}{\sqrt{k}}\right|\leq \frac{|x|}{k^{3/2}}.$$
and the series $\sum_{k\geq }\frac{1}{k^{a}}$ is convergent iff $a>1$.

Answer (score 1):

Use $|\sin \alpha|\leq |\alpha|$ so with fixed $x$
$$\Big|\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{\sin \left(\frac{x}{k}\right)}{\sqrt{k}} \Big|\leq \sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{|x|}{k\sqrt{k}}<\infty$$

Answer (score 1):

More is true.

Since $|\sin(x/k)| \le |x/k|,
\sum \frac{\sin(x/k)}{k^c}
$
converges for any
$c > 0$.